# Why I cant't change the status bar color to white in flutter

Tags: flutter, statusbar

```
// ignore_for_file: constant_identifier_names

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:myapp/config/app_config.dart';
import 'package:myapp/themes/themes.dart';
import 'package:url_strategy/url_strategy.dart';

Future main() async {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.white, // status bar color
      statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark));
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  const ENV = String.fromEnvironment('ENV', defaultValue: 'dev');
  await AppConfig.configEnv(ENV);
  setPathUrlStrategy();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      child: GetMaterialApp(
          theme: theme(),
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: "Myapp",
          home: const HomeScreen()),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to change the color to something else then it works but when I the change color to whit it is not working.is ther any problem in my code.

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
 SystemUiOverlayStyle
    .dark
    .copyWith(
    statusBarColor: Colors.white
    )),
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code I edited.

```
Future main() async {
 runApp(const MyApp());
 SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
  systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.black,
  statusBarColor: Colors.white,
  statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark,
  statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark
 ));
}
```

Comment: Hey there! If you could add a sentence or two explaining why your code works, that would be very helpful!